# Evaluate the limit of the following summation.

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

I came across this question and i am stuck at this.

Evaluate

$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k^4+k^2+1}$

where $n$ goes to infinity.

any ideas?

Comment: Mathematica gives $1/2$ as the limit. But I have no idea of a proof.

Comment: You need to show that the summation is $\frac{n (n+1)}{2 (n^2+n+1)}$

Comment: @jeanmarie yup. U r right. But I.need solution.

Comment: @hamid how can I say that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(thanks to the indication given by @Hamid).

Let us show that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k^4+k^2+1}=\frac{n (n+1)}{2 (n^2+n+1)} \  \ (1)$$

When (1) will be established, a direct consequence is that the limit is $1/2$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$.

(1) is the consequence of the following decomposition into partial fractions:

$$\frac{k}{k^4+k^2+1}=\frac{1}{2(k^2-k+1)}-\frac{1}{2(k^2+k+1)}=f(k)-f(k+1)$$

with $f(k)$ defined by:

$$f(k):=\frac{1}{2(k^2-k+1)}$$

Thus the LHS of (1) is the telescopic sum

$$f(1)-f(2)+f(2)-f(3)+...+f(n)-f(n+1)=f(1)-f(n+1)=\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2(n^2+n+1)}=\frac{n (n+1)}{2 (n^2+n+1)}$$

establishing formula (1).

Comment: @Hamid : how have you had the idea of the finite summation formula ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: I don't really know, it has just popped up in my mind :) then I followed the same procedure.